# JavaScript Song play and pausing

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have managed to play and pause an mp3 file as soon as i click an image, the problem is that every time I select another image(which is meant to play a different mp3 song) it automatically resumes the same song.

My JavaScript:

```
function StartOrStop(audioFile)
  {
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    if(!audie.src)
       audie.src = audioFile;
    if(audie.paused == false)
     {
        audie.pause();
     }
     else
     {
       audie.play();
     }
  }
```

And HTML:

```
<img src="images/play.png" alt="Play Button" width="57" height="50" onclick="StartOrStop('RWY.mp3')">

<img src="images/play.png" alt="Play Button width="57" height="50" onclick="StartOrStop('EL.mp3')">

<audio controls id="myAudio" ></audio>
```

Any suggestion how can I solve this problem?

Comment: this line alt="Play Button width="57" should be alt="Play Button" width="57"

Comment: nop that didnt solve the problem

Comment: I noticed you've asked this question twice. I've answered it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589048/javascript-playing-and-pausing-different-audio-files-using-different-images

Answer (score 1):

You're not assigning a new `src` on click, you're checking to see if it exists first. The second file will never be assigned to `src` since `src` already exists.

**EDIT**

You should instead check to see if `audie.src === audioFile`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this kind of method

```
<audio id="demo1" src="RWY.mp3"></audio>
<div>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo1').play()">Play the Audio</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo1').pause()">Pause the Audio</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo1').volume+=0.1">Increase Volume</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo1').volume-=0.1">Decrease Volume</button>
</div> 
<audio id="demo2" src="EL.mp3"></audio>
<div>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo2').play()">Play the Audio</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo2').pause()">Pause the Audio</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo2').volume+=0.1">Increase Volume</button>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('demo2').volume-=0.1">Decrease Volume</button>
</div>
```

Instead of button you can use image just the tag change.