# Javascript-Playing and pausing different audio files using different images

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hi i am trying to allow multiple images to play and pause different songs , till now i have achieved the playing of songs when the image is selected but when i pause and try resume by clicking on another image the previous file is resumed not the desired one below is the code

Javascript

```
function StartOrStop(audioFile)
  {
    var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    if(!audie.src || audie.src !== audioFile) 
       audie.src = audioFile;
    if(audie.paused == false)
     {
        audie.pause();
     }
     else
     {
       audie.play();
     }
  }
```

HTML

```
<img src="images/play.png" alt="Play Button" width="57" height="50" onclick="StartOrStop('RWY.mp3')">

<img src="images/play.png"  alt="Play Button" width="57" height="50" onclick="StartOrStop('EL.mp3')">

    <audio controls id="myAudio" ></audio>
```

Any Suggestions on how i can fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi not sure why this wouldn't be working. I've reworked your code slight so try this

```
 function StartOrStop(audioFile)
{
var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
//logs to see filenames
console.log("audio src " ,audie.src); //this will output a full url e.g with www.example.com/file.mp3
console.log("file ", audioFile); // this only outputs what you pass in e.g "file.mp3"
//with the www.example.com the if statement below will be false as www.example.com/file.mp3 is not equal to file.mp3. Either change the onclick event of the images to include the full path or edit the if statement to
// if(audie.src.indexOf(audioFile) != -1){

if( audie.src == audioFile){ 
   audie.paused ? audie.play() : audie.pause();
}else{
     audie.src = audioFile;
     audie.play();
}

}
```

I've run this locally on my machine and it works how you want it to

Comment: no when i press the button again to pause it it doesnt pause it just starts the song from the beginning

Comment: Are you sure your urls are correct? I noticed an issue in my solution when using local files. The audie.src will be the full url e.g 'http://example.com/file.mp3' so make sure you pass in the full url in your audioFile variable or remove it from audie.src. You can check this by adding the following code to your method:

console.log("AudioFile: ", audioFile);
console.log("Audie src: ", audie.src);

Make sure they are the same and one doesn't include more url info

Comment: no i tried swapping the url.If u saw carefully i have multiple audio files on my page so i still cant just specify one

Comment: I'm not saying specify one. But in your images on the onclick event you specify "file.mp3" but when you assign it to the audio element and do audio.src if will put the full url to it including the http://www.example.com , so you need to change the onclick event to be onclick=StartOrStop('http://www.fullpathtomyfile.com/file.mp3'). This only works if you specify your domain as part of the filename. I have tested this with different files and not just 1. In firefox add the console.log statements I mentioned above into your startOrStop method and tell me what they output

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the console.log I was suggesting to determine what is going wrong

Comment: but my files are stored locally and do not point out to a file on the internet

Comment: it doesn't matter. Although you can use relative urls e.g "file.mp3"  when you do audie.src it automatically adds the full url to it, it's not me or my code doing that, it's the browser. See my edits above and you can handle this though. Just please try what I said

Answer (score 0):

try this, now its running 
hope it helps you......

JAVASCRIPT Code

```
function Start(audioFile)
{
var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");
    console.log("audio src " ,audie.src);
    console.log("file ", audioFile); 


    if( audie.src == audioFile){
       audie.paused ? audie.play() : audie.pause();
    }else{
     audie.src = audioFile;
     audie.play();
}

}

 function Stop(audioFile)
{
var audie = document.getElementById("myAudio");

console.log("audio src " ,audie.src);
console.log("file ", audioFile);

if( audie.src == audioFile){
   audie.paused ? audie.play() : audie.pause();
}else{
     audie.src = audioFile;
     audie.Pause();
}

}
```

=======================================================
HTML Code

```
<img src="images/play.png" alt="Play Button" width="57" height="50" onclick="Start('RWY.mp3')">
<br>
<img src="images/stop.png"  alt="StopButton" width="57" height="50" onclick="Stop('EL.mp3')">
<br>
    <audio controls id="myAudio" ></audio><br>
```